# Can not install MSSQL 2014 successfully

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to install two node clustered MSSQL 2014 server. I have two MS Server 2012R2 machines, which are clustered in Failover Cluster, they have shared storage attached and when i try to install MSSQL Server on primary node, after going through the whole wizard Database Engine Services feature fails to install an some other features (core features only mgmt is installed). I have tried  to install primary node 5 times and one and the same result.. Install log is attached..

```
    Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2067791871
  Start time:                    2015-10-29 01:38:56
  End time:                      2015-10-29 02:15:24
  Requested action:              InstallFailoverCluster

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Next step for DQ:              Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Next step for FullText:        Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Next step for Replication:     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.


Cluster properties:
  Machine name: MSSQL_NODE1
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

  Machine name: MSSQL_NODE2
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  MSSQL_NODE1
  Machine processor count:       2
  OS version:                    Windows Server 2012
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  Yes

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2014 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2014
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       12
  Installation location:         C:\Users\Administrator.ST1\Desktop\en_sql_server_2014_standard_edition_with_service_pack_1_x64_dvd_6669998\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Standard

  Slipstream:                    True
  SP Level                       1

Product Update Status:
  Success: KB 3058865

Product Updates Selected for Installation:
  Title:                         Microsoft SQL Server 2014  with SP1
  Knowledge Based Article:       KB 3058865
  Version:                       12.1.4100.0
  Architecture:                  x64
  Language:                      1033

  Update Source:                 Slipstream


User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        InstallFailoverCluster
  AGTDOMAINGROUP:                <empty>
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 ST1\Agentadm
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20151029_013856\ConfigurationFile.ini
  ENU:                           true
  ERRORREPORTING:                true
  FAILOVERCLUSTERDISKS:          Cluster Disk 1, Cluster Disk 2, Cluster Disk 3
  FAILOVERCLUSTERGROUP:          SQL Server (SRVSQLCL01)
  FAILOVERCLUSTERIPADDRESSES:    IPv4;10.232.7.109;Cluster Network 2;255.255.254.0
  FAILOVERCLUSTERNETWORKNAME:    SRVSQLCL01
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, REPLICATION, FULLTEXT, DQ
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             E:\
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              DefaultSharePointMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         *****
  SECURITYMODE:                  SQL
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  H:\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 ST1\Engineadm
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           ST1\Administrator
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  G:\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  E:\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  true
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  Slipstream
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            true
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20151029_013856\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x84C00001
  Error description:             The search for mount points failed.  Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=0xF7F8ABE1%400x1C2074D8%401216%401&EvtType=0xF7F8ABE1%400x1C2074D8%401216%401

  Feature:                       Data Quality Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x84C00001
  Error description:             The search for mount points failed.  Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=0xF7F8ABE1%400x1C2074D8%401216%401&EvtType=0xF7F8ABE1%400x1C2074D8%401216%401

  Feature:                       Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x84C00001
  Error description:             The search for mount points failed.  Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=0xF7F8ABE1%400x1C2074D8%401216%401&EvtType=0xF7F8ABE1%400x1C2074D8%401216%401

  Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x84C00001
  Error description:             The search for mount points failed.  Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtType=0xF7F8ABE1%400x1C2074D8%401216%401&EvtType=0xF7F8ABE1%400x1C2074D8%401216%401

  Feature:                       SQL Browser
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Writer
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Setup Support Files
  Status:                        Passed

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

There are no scenario-specific rules.

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20151029_013856\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to provide us the log.  The solution per the information you provided is **"Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again."**

Comment: Install log is up there you can see whole log (strangely formatted text).

Comment: "Status:                        Failed: see logs for details"  - I didn't ask for the log you provided I asked for whatever log this message is speaking of.  The information you have provided indicates how you resolve the error, does doing said remediation not work?

Comment: I'm sorry. The thing which i saw there was: `Error description:             The search for mount points failed.  Error: The system cannot find the path specified.`I think that is the problem which we are looking for but how to fix it. And for what mounting point we are talking about.